# passport deserializeUser not called in sails

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, passport.js, express-jwt

I am using Sails version 0.11 and trying to configure app with jwt authentication.

config/passport.js

```
var passport      = require('passport');
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

module.exports = {

  http: {
    customMiddleware: function(app) {
      console.log('express midleware for passport');
      app.use(jwt({ secret: sails.config.session.secret, credentialsRequired: false}).unless({path: ['/login']}));
      app.use(passport.initialize());
      app.use(passport.session());
    }
  }
};
```

services/passport.js

```
/* other code */
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log(user);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log(id);
  findById(id, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      done(err);
    else if (!user) {
      done(null, false);
    }
    else
      done(null, user);
  });
});
```

AuthController.js

```
module.exports = {

  login: function(req, res) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, info, user) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
      else if (!user) {
        return res.send(info);
      }
      else {
        var token = jwt.sign(user, sails.config.session.secret, {
          expiresInMinutes: 5 // expires in 5 minutes
        });
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token: token
        });
      }
    })(req, res);
  },

  me: function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user);
  }
}
```

Why is my desesializedUser function never called? What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2):

Do you configure the strategy for passport?

In the passport [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport#strategies), the below is mentioned.

> Before authenticating requests, the strategy (or strategies) used by an application must be configured.